# Access Parent class variables in companion Object in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to call static function of one class in other like java , But in kotlin I can not make a static function , and I have to make a companion object in which I have to define my function , But while doing this I am not able to access parent class variables , is there any way I can achieve this in kotlin .

```
class One {

    val abcList = ArrayList<String>()

    companion object {

        fun returnString() {
            println(abcList[0]) // not able to access abcList here
        }
    }
}

class Two {

    fun tryPrint() {
        One.returnString()
    }
}
```

```java
// In Java we can do it like this

class One {

    private static ArrayList<String> abcList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void tryPrint() {
        // assume list is not empty 
        for(String ab : abcList) {
            System.out.println(ab);
        }
    }

    public static void printOnDemand() {
        System.out.println(abcList.get(0));
    }
}

class Two {

    public void tryPrint(){
        One.printOnDemand();
    }
}
```

I want to access fun returnString() like static function of class one like we do in java , if any one have achieved this please help .

Comment: you can't do this in java either, unless abcList is also static. Try moving abcList into the companion object

Comment: how can I make abcList static in kotlin class, as my other function in class one are also using abcList for some operations @TimCastelijns

Comment: Non-static functions/variables aren't accessible from static function, same for Kotlin.

Comment: why don't you just extend `one` class

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your case `abcList` is a member variable of the class. Each instance of a class has their own version of its member variables which means that a static method cannot access them. If you want to access it from your companion object it has to be static too.

```
class One {
    companion object {
        val abcList = ArrayList<String>()

        fun returnString() {
            println(abcList[0])
        }
    }
}

class Two {
    fun tryPrint() {
        One.returnString()
    }
}
```

This code will work, but keep in mind that in this case there will be only one instance of `abcList`. Accessing a member variable from a static function is not possible (not even in Java).

Here's the Kotlin version of your Java example:

```
class One {
    companion object {
        val abcList = ArrayList<String>()

        fun printOnDemand() {
            println(abcList[0])
        }
    }

    fun tryPrint() {
        for (ab in abcList) {
            println(ab)
        }
    }
}

class Two {
    fun tryPrint() {
        One.printOnDemand()
    }
}
```

Comment: I wants to use abcList globally in class one

Comment: By globally you mean you want to change the same ArrayList from every instance from class One?

Comment: I wants to use abcList in other functions of class one ,and add or remove string from abcList from class Two . I can do that easily in java by making abcList static and a static function in class One

Comment: The answer I gave you is the same, by moving the list inside the companion object I made the list static too.

Comment: Please check edited question now , what i wants to achieve . @pshegger

Comment: I added the Kotlin version of your example, this code will do the same thing as the Java one.

Answer (score 1):

Rule: You can't access static properties, members of a class in none static members and you can't access none static properties, members of a class in static members which is the companion object class.
This rule is in both Java and Kotlin. If you want to access a none static member of a class
inside static members you have to declare it inside companion object class.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code for you case.

```
object One {
    val abcList: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()

    fun returnString() {
       println(abcList[0])
    }

    fun printOnDemand() {
       println(abcList[0]);
    }
}

class Two {
    fun tryPrint() {
        One.printOnDemand()
    }
}
```