# How to put methods in companion object of parent class so that they can be inherited in children classes?

Tags: kotlin, generics, inheritance, companion-object

I have two data classes which are very similar to each other.
I want to write a parent class for both of them so they can inherit the common functionality.

My problem is that some methods I want to inherit are needed to be inside `companion object`.

A) `data class Link`

```
import org.json.JSONArray
import org.json.JSONObject

data class Link(
    val name: String,
    val url: String
) {
    var selected: Boolean = false

    fun toggle() { selected = selected.not() }

    companion object {
        fun fromJson(obj: JSONObject): Link = with(obj) {
            Link(getString("name"), getString("url"))
        }

        fun fromJson(arr: JSONArray): List<Link> = with(arr) {
            List(length()) {
                fromJson(getJSONObject(it))
            }
        }

        fun toJson(list: List<Link>): JSONArray = JSONArray().apply {
            list.forEach {
                put(it.toJson())
            }
        }
    }

    fun toJson(): JSONObject = JSONObject().apply {
        put("name", name)
        put("url", url)
    }
}
```

B) `data class DownloadStatus`

```
import org.json.JSONArray
import org.json.JSONObject

data class DownloadStatus(
    val name: String,
    val url: String,
    val path: String,
    var progress: Int = 0
) {
    var selected: Boolean = false

    fun toggle() { selected = selected.not() }

    companion object {
        fun fromJson(obj: JSONObject): DownloadStatus = with(obj) {
            DownloadStatus(getString("name"), getString("url"), getString("path"), getInt("progress"))
        }

        fun fromJson(arr: JSONArray): List<DownloadStatus> = with(arr) {
            List(length()) {
                fromJson(getJSONObject(it))
            }
        }

        fun toJson(list: List<DownloadStatus>): JSONArray = JSONArray().apply {
            list.forEach {
                put(it.toJson())
            }
        }
    }

    fun toJson(): JSONObject = JSONObject().apply {
        put("name", name)
        put("url", url)
        put("path", path)
        put("progress", progress)
    }
}
```

`abstract class Parent`

```
abstract class Parent {
    var selected: Boolean = false

    fun toggle() { selected = selected.not() }

    companion object {

    }

    abstract fun toJson(): JSONObject
}
```

I am stuck here. How to put the methods in `companion object` of the parent class?

Comment: Not really the answer you're looking for, sorry, but you get all this code generated for free with libraries like `kotlinx.serialization`. Is there a particular reason you're using the more "manual" `org.json`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access Parent class variables in companion Object in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57673717/access-parent-class-variables-in-companion-object-in-kotlin)

Comment: @Joffrey I didn't knew about that... will definitely look into it...